# Making particles.js a background

Tags: html, css, particles.js

I'm very new to this whole HTML thing and I'm making a website for school work and stuff. So what I wanted was to make this photo in the background:

[image]

have the particles.js plugin by Vincent Garreau instead. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be massively appreciated.

Website Files: https://mega.nz/#!Dmpi0ACS!Are8WETH3fbCxiaxyOqy7-DGLOBup5rgKODliNPOSsI

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] in the question itself please

Answer (score 0):

## Background Image in HTML and CSS

You don't need a plugin you can just use:

```
#your-div-or-whatever {
   background-image: url('path/to/file.png');
}
```

Check out the below links for more ideas on how you could do this in much simpler CSS or HTML:

[W3 Schools CSS Background-Image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

[W3 Schools HTML Image](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Comment: How would I do it with particles.js because its a script not a .png

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean and why you would want to use a plugin for something which is native in HTML and CSS especially for a website?

Comment: Do you have discord? I might be able to explain better in a video chat

Comment: No i do not, but I have other social medias if you would prefer that to stack overflowe

Comment: Do you have Skype? Or anything i can screen share with?

Comment: Do have some sort of screenshot or example of what you would exactly like to do with particle.js? You're question is not very clear and makes it look as if you just want to embed a photo...